# PHP Activity log

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a web app based on PHP and a DB based on MySQL.
The app registers employees `(table name: colaboradores)` and items `(Table name: ativos)` (like computers and stuff like that) and then on the app it has the `users` table (that basically is for permissions like create and delete records).

The point is, I want every action performed by any user to be registered on a log file (I was thinking on creating a new table on the BD called `log` maybe? ) and show a text field on the page of every item that is register all the life's cycle of that item (For exemple, register on the `log` that the user mike added an Iphone to the employee Sam today).
Any tips of how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. But you could create the new table, and then on every successful crud action, log it there. Getting the custom text such as Iphone or Sam is entirely dependent on how you have structured your classes, system naming conventions to generically get those custom text. Hence why i said this is too broad

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, and thanks for your awnser, so all I need to do is store the actual value on a var and for each row I would output the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use  a log file system its more speedy than database to store the user activity(insert,update,delete) :

```
$file=fopen('activity.log','a');

// in insert condition
if($inser)
{
    fwrite($file,$user->name.' : insert'."\n");


}
// in update condition
if($update)
{
    fwrite($file,$user->name.' : update'."\n");


}
// in delete condition
if($delete)
{
    fwrite($file,$user->name.' : delete'."\n");


}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I was thinking on that, but my boss asked me to do it this way and show it on the webapp :/

Comment: yes you can get values from file just by using `file_get_contents('activity.log')` then work with it on you page

Comment: It isn't creating the log file for some reason... :/

Comment: which system you work with centos ? it could be you dont have a permession on that directory , you can just go to this folder where you want to put the file them make `chmod 777 /home/folder/*` to give access to your apatch to creat files  on that folder

Comment: It's kinda strange that I don't have permissions bc I'm the owner of the machine

Comment: yeah some times system dont give access to apache for specific places ok try to give access and i see

Comment: you can chose the file place where you want just make sure you write the file place on fopen like fopen('/home/activity_folder/activity.log');

Comment: Oh okay it worked, but php seams to not recognize that `insert` and `update` variables (I don't need `delete` tbh) but then, I have the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on diferent pages, so on each page should I create the var `$insert` and `$update` and create the output text ?

Comment: Because that's the other point.. I don't know how the system will validate all the fields and check if they were modified or not :/

Comment: yeah even are on diffrent pages you can just make call fopen('/home/activity_folder/activity.log') on the end of each proccess , you can save it as csv format like `loginname,type,date` then in you activity page that you made call the file and put then on table or what you want

Comment: on the call you can make `$file=file('activity.log');` then make foreach on the array `foreach($rows as $row){$exp=explode(',',$row);$name=$exp[0];...}`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm getting really confuse.. it's the first time i'm working with logs and gotta say that this is messing is me

Comment: logs not that big they are easy to understand , or you can chage it to database  create a table log and insert on it every proccess

Comment: But even on the database, it's that simple to create a table and on the end of the page `create.php` do another query to `INSERT` the data that I want to the log table?<br> I'm kinda confuse with that because when I'm creating a new record I can't register the variable value anywhere because the value will only be processed when the `INSERT`(on the main table) query will sucefully done, right?

Comment: yeah but even if the insert not succefull the insert on table log will work as normal just you need the table log looks  likethis `name,type,date,status` you will add another column call status to show if the insert or update done or not

Comment: i think the both idea are good the log files its good for free mysql storage and datatabse option its good too because you will able to make query faster

Comment: But for the case that u post, i need to put that code before doing the `INSERT` query?

Comment: no after then make  $inser=$db->query('ins....') ; if($insert){$tablelog_insert=$db->query('insert....success')}else{... failed} samething on update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184817/discussion-between-hamzanig-and-carlos-santiago).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for writing to a specified log directory. You just pass in the log message and it creates/updates a log file named after the current date. Be sure to give nginx/apache ownership of the log directory with `chown`.

```
function logActivity($data) {
    file_put_contents("/home/logs/" . date("m-d-Y"), date("h:i a") . ": " . $data . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but it can't be an external file but an visible text on the app so the users can see all the life's cycle of some item that was registered

Comment: You can use `file_get_contents()` in a similar way to just display the logs.

Comment: I will have many and many records, it is possible to have a log file for each one and display it on each item's "Info" page?